# Brightness not getting changed in Ubuntu 18.10 in Dell Inspiron 5577

Tags: nvidia, dell, brightness, 18.10

I had dual booted my Dell Inspiron 5577 (NVIDIA Geforce 1050) i5 Laptop with Windows 10 as Ubuntu 18.04. But it appears that there is no option to change brightness in the options from settings of top right corner of screen.

[image: Dash menu screenshot]

Function keys for changing brightness (F11 & F12) are not working
(other function keys are working fine.)

Also I tried to install third party software for changing the brightness, but they didn't work.

Also tried to make changes in `/etc/default/grub` from:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

and this too:

```
Option     "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
```

But this didn't work either.

Also I tried writing a shell script and to add a user defined keyboard shortcut for adjusting the brightness, but this didn't work out for me either.

I have upgraded to Ubuntu 18.10 but none of the above solutions worked.

Details of current installed Ubuntu:

[image: Ubuntu about screenshot]

I don't know if it's relevant, but I tried NVIDIA Driver update and after completion and rebooting, my laptop didn't boot. So I had to again uninstall the NVIDIA Drivers update. So currently haven't upgraded the driver.

Does anyone have any solution?

Comment: What's the output of `ls /sys/class/backlight/ ` ?

Comment: I think it's because of graphics drivers. Try to install them again. [This](https://askubuntu.com/q/61396/816190) might help.

Comment: I am not getting anything on executing 'ls /sys/class/backlight/' command. That folder is empty.

Comment: @Kulfy On Installing the nvidia driver and rebooting, my laptop never starts. So from recovery mode I had to purge it to boot my laptop.

Comment: @JaineelMamtora Try another version of the nvidia drivers, because that's the solution...